# make all fatal error, when i am compiling Makefile

Tags: installation, caffe, fatal-error

I am getting error as shown below while running make all command. 
fatal error: google/protobuf/arena.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Comment: You need to post a more detailed error log and also tell us which OS you're using.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16.04, CUDA 8.0 & python 2.7.

Comment: As Harsh asked, please give a more detailed error log. Please also post your makefile.config. What instructions have you followed for installation? Have you tried following the instructions in the video? Does it compile for just the CPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you don't have `protobuf` installed or it is outdated. To install, run the following command

```
sudo apt-get install -y libprotobuf-dev libleveldb-dev libsnappy-dev libhdf5-serial-dev protobuf-compiler
```

In case it is outdated, you need to compile protobuf from the [source](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md).

Answer (score 2):

```
cd ~/caffe
sudo make clean
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
sudo apt-get install libprotobuf-dev libleveldb-dev libsnappy-dev libopencv-dev libboost-all-dev libhdf5-serial-dev
sudo apt-get install libgflags-dev libgoogle-glog-dev liblmdb-dev protobuf-compiler
pip install protobuf
sudo make all
sudo make test
sudo make runtest
```

Comment: Ok, I will try. Thank you.

Comment: After that one error i have found this error. will you please tell me what things i should have to do..The error is                                                 .build release/cuda/src/caffe/layers/hd5_output_layer.o] Error 127

Comment: If this s answer please sign as an answer. And ask new question about your new error.